# Android connection to a database locally through Wifi without a webservice

Tags: android

I have seen a lot tutorial where we can connect to a remote database but what if i need to connect through a database locally(i do not want data to travel through www). Specifically how to connect to database which is local and i wish to connect to this database through wifi.